# How to find the host where its has mysql client and path?

Tags: mysql

How to find the host where its has mysql client and path ?

I can do 'which mysql' . But path would be differ and some not configurated .

is there any other way to find in the host mysql client intsalled or not ?

Comment: Can you rephrase? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Which client do you mean? the mysql client that lets you run queries? or the .dll/.so libraries that provide the client services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying you have more than one mysql client installed on the host computer, and you are trying to find the right one?

```
find / -type f -regex '.*/mysql' 2>/dev/null
```

This should show you all files named mysql, which is the name of the mysql client binary. You will have to figure out which one to use from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
which mysql
```

gives you the path to the binary which would suggest it is installed.

Depending on what flavor of Linux you are running you can check to see if the client was installed with a package manager:

Debian/Ubuntu

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

RedHat/Fedora

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```